# dotnet Core - Getting the correct location of a csv file in my project for streamreader

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I thought this would be easy but I am having trouble knowing how to reference a csv file in one of my projects.

Here it is in the solutions display.

[image]

The code that is referencing it gets an invalid operations error meaning it wasnt able to find the file and it wasnt.. checked via stepping and its null.

```
public class CATALOGStateInitialiser : ICATALOGStateInitialiser
{
    public void CATALOGInitialiseStates(CATALOGContext context)
    {
        if (context == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));

        if (context.States.Any()) return; //DB table data already created.

        using var resourceStream = GetType().Assembly
            .GetManifestResourceStream(
                "JobsLedger.INITIALISATION.SUBURB.Initialisations.AddressCSV.states.csv");
        var reader = new StreamReader(resourceStream ?? throw new InvalidOperationException(), Encoding.UTF8);

        reader.Dispose();

        var stringStates = reader.ReadToEnd();

        var stringSeparators = new[] {"\r\n"};

        var states = stringStates.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.None)
            .Select(FromCsv)
            .Where(a => a != null)
            .ToList();

        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public static State FromCsv(string csvLine)
    {
        if (csvLine == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(csvLine));


        var values = csvLine.Split(',');

        if (values.Length <= 1) return null;
        var state = new State
        {
            StateName = values[0],
            StateShortName = values[1]
        };

        return state;
    }
}
```

This is the line that tries to locate the actual csv file:

```
        using var resourceStream = GetType().Assembly
            .GetManifestResourceStream(
                "JobsLedger.INITIALISATION.SUBURB.Initialisations.AddressCSV.states.csv");
```

..and this is the line that is throwing the error having not found the file:

```
    var reader = new StreamReader(resourceStream ?? throw new InvalidOperationException(), Encoding.UTF8);
```

so I have clearly not put the right path or syntax or both.

Given states.csv location in the INITIALISATION library project how do I reference this correctly?

**UPDATE**

Code was slightly incorrect in that I disposed of the Reader before reading it as well as having the wrong path. I also did what dimlucas said although in the end I changed it to embeddedResource and "copy if newer" in the "Copy to" option.

Here is the code that now works.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using JobsLedger.CATALOG;
using JobsLedger.CATALOG.ENTITIES;
using JobsLedger.INITIALISATION.CATALOG.Initialisations.Interfaces;

namespace JobsLedger.INITIALISATION.CATALOG.Initialisations
{
    public class CATALOGStateInitialiser : ICATALOGStateInitialiser
    {
        public void CATALOGInitialiseStates(CATALOGContext context)
        {
            if (context == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));

            if (context.States.Any()) return; //DB table data already created.

            using var resourceStream = GetType().Assembly
                .GetManifestResourceStream(
                    "JobsLedger.INITIALISATION.AddressCSV.states.csv");
            var reader = new StreamReader(resourceStream ?? throw new InvalidOperationException(), Encoding.UTF8);

            var stringStates = reader.ReadToEnd();

            reader.Dispose();

            var stringSeparators = new[] {"\r\n"};

            var states = stringStates.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.None)
                .Select(FromCsv)
                .Where(a => a != null)
                .ToList();

            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        public static State FromCsv(string csvLine)
        {
            if (csvLine == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(csvLine));


            var values = csvLine.Split(',');

            if (values.Length <= 1) return null;
            var state = new State
            {
                StateName = values[0],
                StateShortName = values[1]
            };

            return state;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What build action have you set on your file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio, click on the file and go to the properties Window

In the `Build Action` option choose either `Resource` or `Content`.

In the `Copy to Output Directory` option choose `Copy always`

This ensures that the file is moved to the bin folder when you build your project. Right now, the .csv file is only part of your source code, it's not part of the final binary that is eventually run by .NET Core. The first option ensures that the file is included with the binaries and the second option ensures that the file is copied over on every subsequent build operation to avoid syncing issues.

Comment: You don't need to copy to output for these build actions.

Comment: @Crowcoder You **do** if you expect to find the file there. Wich is what he did.

Comment: Apologies, for Content, yes. Not for Resource though.

Comment: Just my usual Caveat: The Programm direcetory is not usually a good place for any modifyable file. For early learning (wich this seems to be) it works. If it is static/only saves on updates it also works. But in production Systems and if the file is modifable, they can not be in the programm directory. One of the designated Special Folders has to be used instead: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder

Comment: Hi Christopher, is there a tutorial on how to use special folders for things like csv files and such. This obviously wont change much but id like to put it in the right directory to start with.. and use it from there.